# Declaring a constant referring to another constant in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How do I declare a constant, which refers to another constant or module? For example, I need to declare a constant named root, which needs to refer to $window

Some pseudo-code:

```
app.constant('root', function ($window) {
    var root = '/';
    switch ($window.location.hostname) {
        case 'someserver':
            root = '/subtree/';
            break;
        default:
    }
    return root;
});
```

How to inject $window in this declaration?

Comment: Why not make this a service instead?

Answer (score 0):

A constant is something that cannot be configured or instantiated or even decorated. And so, a function cannot be defined as a constant provider. All it can be a object literal that can be injected everywhere in the app scope.

The alternative option would be to use services as @Mathew suggested.